# Cannot add any content in my custom cell using a .xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I cannot get the content from my custom cell's xib file, the cells are empty, the cell .xib file only contains a UILabel, then the code in the Master class (in a Master-Detail project) is as follow :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
//[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
```

}

Where self configureCell is for Core Data, to test my UILabel, I did not want to get the value from Core Data, so I commented this line.
The "custom class" is set to "MyCell" in the storyboard, the identifier is the same one...

I also tried this in my class MyCell:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
self.ibLabel.text = @"allo";
}
```

but my cells are still empty... The height of each cell is also the same in the .xib as in the code...

---

EDIT #1:

This worked to register the cell custom class:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you register the nib in viewDidLoad:

```
    self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: yeah thank you, why do we have to register the nib if it is the same name as the class? It works fine now, thanks a lot

Comment: Looks like it's just part of the wire-up process that Apple requires. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do you try in the cell forRow:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath {
  MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"  forIndexPath:indexPath];
  cell.ibLabel.text = @"allo";
  return cell;
```

If this don't work, you must be sure that "Cell" is also the identifier in the storyboard, and in the storyboard the class is MyCell.

First, a stupid question: Have you implement this method and It's not returning 0 ?

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 return 5; // To test
 }
```

Second:
     In storyboaard change de backgroundColor of your custom cell, in order to be sure that is this cell painting.

Comment: thanks but still nothing... the class is indeed "MyCell" and the identifier "Cell", Core Data is not filling the cells anymore, and my cell class is a basic class with a .xib file... That's all.

Comment: @Paul more things to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot Onik IV for your help, the answer was to use registerNib and the cell now appears well, thanks for the support! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the cell. It might be the first cell and you haven't got one before...

> This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or nib file you previously registered.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    MyCell *cell;
    cell = (MyCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MyCell alloc] init];
        cell.ibLabel.text = @"allo";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, still nothing... I removed the tableView, added a new one, the outlets seems to be added automatically (the data and delegate are set to "Master"), also I ask for 1 row and 1 section but there are still plenty of empty lines, is it normal?

Comment: What did you mean with "Master"? You have to link the delegate and dataSource to the File's Owner of the tableView and you have to declare it as a **UITableViewDelegate** and **UITableViewDataSource**

Comment: Thanks LucaD, it works fine now, I had to register the nib name, see the answer below, thanks a lot for the support! ;)